# c# Drawing a small image on big PictureBox

Tags: c#, image, picturebox

Imagine you are drawing a 10x10 .png picture on 700x700 PictureBox in WinForms app. The problem is the shifting picture on 0.5 pixel up and left on PictureBox.
The test picture you can watch here:
[image]
It is square with 1px width border.

And the resulting PictureBox looks like:
[image]
You can see, that border has not the same width everywhere and is shifted on 0.5 px left and up (I called px an px equivalent on PictureBox, because this px from 10x10 picture is like 100x100 real pixels).

In code I use InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor for correct displaying small picture on big canvas. But it does not change the result.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        testBmp = new Bitmap("some_path_here\\test.png");
        drawBitmapOnPictureBox(pictureBox1, testBmp);
    }

    private void drawBitmapOnPictureBox(PictureBox pictureBox, Bitmap bmp)
    {
        if (pictureBox.Size != bmp.Size)
        {
            float zoom = 60.0f;
            Bitmap zoomed = new Bitmap((int)(bmp.Width * zoom), (int)(bmp.Height * zoom));

            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(zoomed))
            {
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                g.DrawImage(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, zoomed.Size));
            }
            pictureBox.Image = zoomed;
        }
        else
            pictureBox.Image = bmp;
    }

    Bitmap testBmp;
}
```

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21248265/1132334), would it apply?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pixeloffsetmode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: TY, guys. You are both have helped me.

Comment: It's a .Net bug, as far as I can see; there's no sense in having to set that `PixelOffsetMode` to `Half` to make sure it is _not_ shifted half a pixel. It's possible it only reacts this way in `NearestNeighbor` scaling (haven't tested outside that), but that's not really an excuse...